# custom validator with regex for non-keyboard characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I would like to write custom validator like i`m trying below

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.validates_characters(*attr_names)
    validates_each(attr_names) do |record, attr_name, value|
      unless value.nil?
        regex = /^[[a-zA-Z\][0-9]\]]\\$@^`,|%;.~()\/{}:?\[=\]\+\-_#!<&\s]*$/
        record.errors.add(attr_name, 'invalid characters') unless regex.match(value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this regex => `` /^[[a-zA-Z\][0-9]\]]\\$@^`,|%;.~()\/{}:?\[=\]\+\-_#!<&\s]*$/ `` in rubular but it have some errors.

I would like to allow only for this characters:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
1234567890
$@^`,|%;.~()/\{}:?[]=-+_#!<>& and spaces
```

So this string is not valid => `"  © gfdgfd 0543"`

Is better way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to match those characters you could just use this:

```
[\$@\^`,\|%;\.~\(\)/\\\{\}:\?=\-\+_#!<>&\sA-Z0-9\[\]]+$
```

Comment: ```/^[\$@\^`,\|%;\.~\(\)\/\\\{\}:\?=\-\+_#!<>&\sa-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+$/``` This exacly. But why my regex is wrong ??

Comment: you are missing a few escapes... i.e. on $ { }?